# I can't log in in Kohana 3.2 ORM Auth module?

Tags: kohana-3.2, kohana-auth

Well, thats a trouble. The code is simple:

```
public function action_index()
{

    $post = $this->request->post();

    if ($post) {    
        // if I type it like this, manually - it will work
        $success = Auth::instance()->login('admin','password');

    }

    if (isset($success) and $success) { echo "Пользователь залогинен"; }

}
```

Unfortunately it log in only a first record in the database, which is admin as by default config was in the table, If I create a new user. Like this:

```
$auth = Auth::instance();
        $user = new Model_User();
        $user->username = "Victor";
        $user->$auth->hash_password('psw123');
        $user->email = "me@email.com";
        $user->save();
```

And than use it like I said, only with a real data as

`$post["email"] or $post["username"] with $post["password"]`

code:

```
if ($post) {    
    // the values from posts: 'Victor' or 'me@email.com` & 'psw123'
    $success = Auth::instance()->login('me@email.com','psw123');

}
```

it will not log in me.

**upd** I can't login as admin, but all working perfectly if I'll change the role to `login` (it's 1 in the database). But if the role will be set to `2` (it's an `admin` role) it will not accept me, even do not make an instance of `Auth`.

```
        $post = $this->request->post();

        $success = Auth::instance()->login($post['email'], $post['pass']);


        if ($success)
        {
            echo "SUCCESS!";
        }
```

Once again, if the role will be 2 (it means admin) this is not will Success me instead of `login` role.

What can be a reason of this trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a default ORM auth driver. You don't need to hash your password when saving a new user - it is done automatically by a filter in the model. So saving a new user should look something like that:

```
$user = ORM::factory("user");
$user->username = "Victor";
$user->password = "psw123";
$user->email = "me@email.com";
$user->save();
```

Comment: Yes, though I forgot about a roles also. So no it's fine! Thank you anyway!

Comment: Hi again and I am again need some help. Watch **upd**.

Comment: From what I understand you're using roles _login_ and _admin_ exclusively. All users with privileges to log in need a _login_ role. So your administrator user should have both _login_ and _admin_ roles.